# Java Variable Scope - Instance and class variables

Tags: java, variables

I am new to Java and trying to learn by myself. I wrote the below code and I was wondering why the output is not as I expect. Below is the code I have written:

```
public class Roughwork {

    public static int classVar = 25;

    public void getValue(int a){
        classVar = a;
        System.out.println(classVar);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Roughwork test = new Roughwork();
        System.out.println(classVar);
        test.getValue(30);
        System.out.println(classVar);
    }

}
```

and the output of this program is:

```
25
30
30
```

I expected the output to be

```
25
30
25
```

What exactly is happening and What I have to do to get my expected output?

Comment: Remove the `static` keyword. Then go and read about what it does.

Comment: @user2810706 you're changing the value of the variable. Why are you wondering that it was changed?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: The value I have changed is in (getValue) method, so I was thinking it will be confined to that method and the final classVar value will be taken as 25 instead of 30

Comment: @user2810706 `static` variables are shared among all instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClassVar is declared static.

```
public static int classVar = 25;
```

This means that it is not tied to an instance of `Roughwork`. It is a global variable if you will. You can call this variable even from other classes in your application like this:

```
Roughwork.classVar
```

To get your expected behaviour, change your code to this:

```
public class Roughwork {

    public int classVar = 25;

    public void getValue(int a){
        classVar = a;
        System.out.println(classVar);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Roughwork test = new Roughwork();
        System.out.println(test.classVar);
        test.getValue(30);
        Roughwork test2 = new Roughwork();
        System.out.println(test2.classVar);
    }

}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working.. I still get 25 30 30

Comment: It should actually give a compile time error if you remove the static keyword. I'll add a fixed code example.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you change it to 30 and don't change it back to 25. (`static` means it is the same for all instances of class)

```
    System.out.println(classVar); //25
    test.getValue(30);            //30
    System.out.println(classVar); //30 - you don't change variable back to 25
```

To fix it add `classVar = 25` after `test.getValue` or remove `static` modifier on `classVar` definition.

Answer (score 0):

A static variable is shared by all instances of the class. and in case of instance variable each instance of class have different copy.

Static variable memory allocate at compile time, They are loaded at load time and initialized at class initialization time and in case of instance variable everything is done at run time.

To make this example interesting: 
Create new instances of Roughwork, try to change the value and give it a try.

```
Roughwork test = new Roughwork();
Roughwork test2 = new Roughwork();
System.out.println(classVar);

test.getValue(30);
test2.getValue(25);
System.out.println(classVar);
```

Reference this thread for example to understand clearly:[Class Variable & Instance Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486392/what-is-the-difference-between-an-instance-and-a-class-static-variable-in-java)