# java language Object and Variables

Tags: java

IN java Language ,when we create an object in method, is Static variables are load in the object ?

```
public class A{     
      static int x =12; 

       void m1(){ 
               int x=2;
              A a = new A(); 
               a.x=3;
           System.out.println(a.x); 

       } 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        A a = new A(); 
          a.m(); 


    } 
}
```

Comment: your code wont compile

Comment: `a.m(); ` should give you error.

Comment: you should declare your **m1** method as **static** first.

Comment: @HelpingHands I think he doesn't need to declare m1 as static.

Comment: Change `a.m();` to `a.m1();`

Comment: @proudandhonour May be then how he will be able to access method in main class?

Comment: @HelpingHands He is already accessing m1 using object of class. If he would be calling m1 directly then it required to declare m1 as static.

Comment: I see , Got your point. thanks :)

Comment: @Helping Hands he will access it exactly the way he's doing it in his question.

Comment: What do you mean by `is Static variables are load in the object ?` ?

Answer (score 0):

> is Static variables are load in the object ?

No,they are not.Static variables are class level variables.

### See Also

- [What is the difference between an instance and a class (static)
  variable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486392/what-is-the-difference-between-an-instance-and-a-class-static-variable-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are only created once, at the first time an instance is created. So creating a second instance will not change the value of **x**. For this example the output should be  *3*.

Answer (score 0):

> Static variable’s value is same for all the object(or instances) of the class or in other words you can say that all instances(objects) of the same class share a single copy of static variables.

They are loaded at runtime.

> Static means: that the variable belong to the class, and not to instances of the class. So there is only one value of each static variable, and not n values if you have n instances of the class.

This is the code free of mistakes.

```
 public class A{     
  static int x =12; 

   void m1(){ 
           x=2;
          A a = new A(); 
           a.x=3;
       System.out.println(a.x); 

   } 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    A a = new A(); 
      a.m1(); 


  } 
}
```

Comment: sorry guys I have some mistake There should be a.m1(); in the main method so any way if the static variables are not load in the object why the  value in X is change in my Question...???