# In Java are object attributes passed by reference to other classes

Tags: java, class, attributes

If I have a class like such:

```
public class First {
   int x = 1;
}
```

and a second class:

```
class Main {
   public static void main(string args[]) {
      First someObject = new First();
      someObject.x = 2;
   }
}
```

is only `someObject.x` equal to 2 or would any object of class First being created afterwards be initialized with it's x attribute being equal to 2. If not, how would one change the default value of x for any object being made of class First?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between an instance and a static variable  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204589/static-vs-instance-variables-difference

Comment: By changing `int x = 1;` to some other value. Usually one would pass a value in the constructor. In fact, one would not typically use this pattern of initialization. I say typically, because a `Factory` or `Builder` pattern might look something like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between an instance and a class (static) variable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486392/what-is-the-difference-between-an-instance-and-a-class-static-variable-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to read about what "pass by reference" really means.  (For example, [here](https://courses.washington.edu/css342/zander/css332/passby.html).)  Passing semantics refer to what happens to arguments in a procedure/method/subroutine/function call.  In your example, there is no "passing" going on at all when you are assigning to the `x` field.

So your

> In Java are object attributes passed by reference to other classes

is a meaningless and/or irrelevant question.  (But the plain answer is that Java does not support "pass by reference".  Period.)

---

As for what I think you are *trying* to ask, lets start with some facts:

- The `Field` class declares `x` as an instance field.
- Each instance of `First` has its own "copy" of the `x` field.
- The `x` field is part of one and only one instance.  It is not shared with any other `First` instance.
- This is **irrespective** of the declared type of `x` ... modulo that a field whose declared type is a *reference type* will contain a reference to an object rather than the object itself.  (But `int` is not a *reference type*.)
- The `new First()` expression creates a new instance of the `First` class that is distinct from all other (past, present or future) instances of `First` and returns its reference.

So, in this code:

```
  First f1 = new First();
  First f2 = new First();
  f1.x = 2;
  System.out.println(f2.x);   // prints 1.
```

We have two instances of `First` that `f1` and `f2` refer to (point at) distinct `First` instances.  If you change the `x` field of one instance does not change the `x` field of the other intance.  They are different fields.

---

However, if you had declared `x` as `static` in `First`, then `x` is no longer a distinct field for each `First` instance.  It is now a shared by all instances of `First`.

---

> As an addendum, how would one change the default value of x in the First class such that any new instance made afterwards would have a difference value of x to start?

Firstly `int x = 1;` in `First` is not defining a "default" value in the sense that Java uses that term.  It is actually an initialization.  (A default value is what you see if you DON'T have an initialization.)

If you wanted to implement application specific default value that is common to all instances of `First` and that can be changed retrospectively, you need to implement it in Java code.  Maybe something like this:

```
    public class First {
        static int defaultX = 1;
        private int x;
        private boolean xSet = false;

        public int getX() {
            return xSet ? x : defaultX;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
            this.xSet = true;
        }
    }
```

Note that in order to implement the defaulting behavior we want, we have to hide the `x` field (make it private) and implement the desired behavior in the getter and setter methods.

Comment: Thank you! This is a helpful response, though as an addendum, how would one change the default value of ``x`` in the ``First`` class such that any new instance made afterwards would have a difference value of ``x`` to start?